# localStorage security error in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I get an error when trying to access localStorage or sessionStorage under my node-webkit app:

```
Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
```

I didn't find anyone anywhere talking or asking help regarding this issue.

Comment: You're opening a data-url, like `data:text/html, <html contenteditable>`, and local storage isn't supported in data-urls. Here's the issue -> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304828

Comment: Wow, thank you, well spotted ! So I'm facing this issue right after opening the devtools, that redirect to a data:text/html error page (node-webkit page). Wondering why I'm the only one reporting those 2 "events" with node-webkit.